# Java - Why don't my mice move correctly?

Tags: java, methods, interface, abstract-class

I am currently working on a program that shows the movements of a critter in a field.  The critters are marked by a char (example: 'M' for mouse) and each have their own way of movement.  The method that I am having trouble with is a method that should make my Mouse critter move.

- They **should be** moving in diagonals (NORTH then EAST or WEST. EAST, then NORTH or SOUTH) a certain amount of times and then changes diagonal directions.

  - The amount of times the mice move diagonally is controlled by `myCount`.  if `myCount` is less than `myTarget`, then the mice should move diagonally.  The mice change direction when `myCount` is equal to `myTarget`.  Then `myCount` is set back to 0.  I want my mice to move in a diagonal 8 times before changing diagonal directions.
- However, **instead** my mice sometimes go diagonally for a little bit, but they always end up moving up then down or left then right over and over about 5 times.

[Here](http://prntscr.com/7y5zh5) is what my program's output looks like. (The S are stones that don't move, they are considered another critter in this case).

**The interface:**

```
public interface Critter
{
   public static final int NORTH = 0;
   public static final int WEST = 1;
   public static final int SOUTH = 2;
   public static final int EAST = 3;
   public static final int CENTER = 4;

   public char getChar();
   public int getMove(CritterInfo theInfo);
}
```

**The abstract class:**

```
public abstract class AbstractCritter implements Critter
{
   private char myCritterName;

   public AbstractCritter(final char theChar)
   {
      myCritterName = theChar;
   }
   public char getChar()
   {
      return myCritterName;
   }
}
```

**The method I am having issues with:**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Mouse extends AbstractCritter
{
   private int myDirection;
   private int myCount;
   private boolean myFirst;
   private int myTarget;
   private Random myRand;
   private int myCheck;

   public Mouse()
   {
      super('M');
      myRand = new Random();
      myDirection = myRand.nextInt(4);
      myCount = 0;
      myFirst = false;
      myTarget = 16;
      myCheck = 0;
   }
   public int getMove(CritterInfo theInfo)
   {
      if (myCount == myTarget)
      {
         myCount = 0;
         int direction = myRand.nextInt(4);
         myFirst = false;

      }
      int direction = myDirection;
      int direction2 = myRand.nextInt(4);
      myCount++;

      if (!myFirst)
      {

         myCheck = myRand.nextInt(2);
         if (myDirection == NORTH || myDirection == SOUTH)
         {
            if (myCheck == 0)
            {
               direction2 = EAST;
            }
            else
            {
               direction2 = WEST;
            }
         }
         else if (myDirection == EAST || myDirection == WEST)
         {
            if (myCheck == 0)
               {
                  direction2 = NORTH;
               }
               else
               {
                  direction2 = SOUTH;
               }
         }
         myFirst = true;
      }

      if (myCount % 2 == 0)
      {
         return direction;
      }
      else
      {
         return direction2;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an `enum` to hold the two different states your mice can be in, it becomes much, much less confusing. Switch between the two states every 8 moves, and then use the `enum` itself to tell you which movement rules you should be using.

The key part of the logic is this line here:

```
int offset = 2 - ((index / 2) * 2);
```

Index will be `0,1` if the direction is `NORTH, SOUTH`, and it will be `2,3` if the direction is `EAST, WEST`. Dividing and then multiplying by two makes it be `0` for `NORTH, SOUTH`, and makes it be `2` for `EAST, WEST`. Then we use `2 -` that value to flip it around, and then we add `1` randomly to choose an orthogonal direction again.

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Mouse extends AbstractCritter {
  private static final int[] allDirections = { NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST };
  private static final Random myRand = new Random();

  private final int myTarget = 16;
  private int myCount = 0;
  private int firstDirection;
  private int secondDirection;

  public Mouse() {
    super('M');
    randomizeDirection();
  }

  public int getMove(CritterInfo info)
  { 
    myCount++;
    if(myCount == myTarget) {
      randomizeDirection();
      myCount = 0;
    }
    return myCount % 2 == 0 ? firstDirection : secondDirection;
  }

  private void randomizeDirection() {
    int index = myRand.nextInt(4);
    firstDirection = allDirections[index];
    int offset = 2 - ((index / 2) * 2); // this turns 0, 1 -> 2; 2, 3 -> 0
    secondDirection = allDirections[offset + myRand.nextInt(2)];
  } 
}
```